# Variable value is not being cleared

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

This code displays parsed data from php the problem is when I select another set of data which are the parsed the previous data are not being cleared. I have tried emptying the var `json` but without any positive result.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".chooseSub").on("click",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var display = $(this).attr("title");
    var idx = 0;
    $.post("includes/learnFunctions.php", {
       learnThis:display
    }, function(data) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (json == 0) {
            $("#spanQ").html("Nothing to show!");
        } else {
            workData(json, idx);
        }
    });
});  

function workData(json, idx){
    function next() {            
        if (idx > (json.length - 1)) {
            idx = 0;
        }
        console.log(idx+" next() start");           
        var text1 = json[idx].question;
        var text2 = json[idx].answer;
        $("#spanQ").html("<p>" + text1 + "</p>");
        $("#spanA").html("<p>" + text2 + "</p>");
        console.log(idx,text1,json);
        console.log(json );           
        idx++;
    }
    $(".test").on("click",function(){
        next();
    });
}

}); //doc ready
```

this problem can be simulated here

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function workData(custVar){
        var idx =0;
        function again(){
            console.warn(custVar); 
            if (idx > (custVar.length - 1)) {
                idx = 0;
            }         
            var text1 = custVar[idx];
            $("#spanQ").html("<p>" + text1 + "</p>");
            console.log(idx,text1,custVar);         
            idx++;
        }
        $("#id4").on("click",function(){       
            again();
        });
    }
    var customVar1 =  ["green", "black", "red", "blue", "yellow"];
    var customVar2 =  ["one","two", "three", "four", "five"];
    $("#id1").on("click", function(){
       workData(customVar1);
    });
    $("#id2").on("click", function(){
       workData(customVar2);
    });
}); //doc ready
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="id1">Colors</div>
    <br/>
    <div id="id2">Numbers</div>
    <br/>
    <div id="id4">RUN</div>
    <br />
    <span id="spanQ"></span>                            
</div>                        
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried couple of different approaches but none of them is working for the interval scenario.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var idx = 0;  
    function workData(custVar){      
        clearInterval(myInterval);   
        function again(){
            if (idx > (custVar.length - 1)) {
                idx = 0;
            }         
            text1 = custVar[idx];
            $("#spanQ").html("<p>" + text1 + "</p>");
            console.log(idx,text1,custVar);
            idx++;
        }
        var myInterval = setInterval(again, 2000);
    }
    function manStep(custVar){
        if (idx > (custVar.length - 1)) {
            idx = 0;
       }         
       text1 = custVar[idx];
       $("#spanQ").html("<p>" + text1 + "</p>");
       console.log(idx,text1,custVar);
       idx++;
    };
    var customVar1 =  ["green", "black", "red", "blue", "yellow"];
    var customVar2 =  ["one","two", "three", "four", "five"];
    $("#id1").on("click", function(){
        workData(customVar1);
    }); 
    $("#id2").on("click", function(){
        workData(customVar2);
    });
    $("#id3").on("click", function(){
       clearInterval(interval); 
       var interval = setInterval(function(){manStep(customVar1);}, 2000);
    });
    $("#id4").on("click", function(){
        clearInterval(interval); 
        var interval = setInterval(function(){manStep(customVar2);}, 2000);
    });  
}); //doc ready
```

Comment: You're sure it's not a caching issue ?

Comment: have you tested the request results?. user Chrome in network tab to see what is your request is sending/receiving.

Comment: you may have more the one controls with "chooseSub" class. Please review it

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. The sending and receiving seems to be ok, the problem is that the parsed data are not being cleared after new request. I have set up a test site here http://test.d-kozak.com.

Comment: when i request from the menu 'Test sub one' and then 'Test sub two' i can see in the console that the loop is going through both of them

Comment: Actually, I don't see any non-clearing on the test site. When I click on "Click to display", the words in both cards seem to be properly replaced (Firefox 25). Is this problem already resolved?

Comment: @denisw still not resolved, it looks ok in the display, but if you look into console you will notice that the first parsed set is still being processed. This is not problem when you do manual click but if I add something like var interval = setInterval(next, 2000); it will display the previous values with incorrect timing

Answer (score 0):

If you add an event handler with `$(".test").on("click", ...)`, this does not cause any previous handlers to be removed. Instead, every run of `workData()` registers an *additional* action to carry out on clicking the `.test` element. This is why you are seeing as many log outputs as calls to `workData()` were made.

To get rid of this problem, you should remove any existing `"click"` event handler before adding a new one. jQuery offers the [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function for this purpose:

```
var test = $(".test");
test.off("click");
test.on("click", ...);
// or: test.off("click").on("click", ...)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked nicely when using .on("click"), but how do I fix the same issue when this is running through setInterval(runFunction, timeOut); where there is no handler just the function?

Comment: `setInterval` returns an ID which can be used to remove the interval callback with `clearInterval`.  See the [relevant docs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setInterval).

Comment: I have tested clearInterval but no luck, pls see above.

Comment: You declared your interval ID variable at function scope, which means that it will be deleted as soon as a call to the surrounding function returns. This means that the value of `myInterval` you set in one `workData` call will not be accessible to the next calll, unless you declare `myInterval` outside of the function. The [MDN section on variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FValues%2C_variables%2C_and_literals#Variable_scope) has more information.

Comment: finally it's working, thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction :)